# How to handle unsaved changes in Tab control in C# WPF when user switch from one tab to another tab

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs

Need to prompt the user with "OK and Cancel" message box. If user clicks OK, then the changes are discarded and switch to another tab. If user clicks Cancel, then the application should stay back on the same tab for the user to Save.

Tried to resolve using PreviewMousedown and SelectionChanged event from code behind, But the child control is also firing this event when they undergo change. Observed that the child control event is propagated to Parent tab control. Please suggest with code snippet on how to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TabControl's SelectionChanged event in code behind to track the selected tab and when it changes:

```
class MainWindow
{
   private int selectedIndex = 0;

    private void tabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Source == tabControl)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Tab has changed. Previous tab was " + selectedIndex + "; new tab is " + tabControl.SelectedIndex);
            selectedIndex = tabControl.SelectedIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

Checking that the source is the TabControl itself (`if (e.Source == tabControl)`) guarantees the event is received from the correct source.

In this event you can prompt the user and switch back to the original tab if they want to continue editing or save their data.